# Data structures in real world

Tags: data-structures

I know C++, C#...and  done with data structures class. Though, in data structures class, at school we just learned the concept (or at most the pseudocode) of data structures, but not in real world of coding (implementation of those concept).
Do I need to turn that concept of data structures in to real world of coding before finding a job? 
I know it's good to turn those data structures in to real world of coding (implementation),but it will take along time to do that and currently I real need a job.

Comment: fist lesson is stackoverflow is a great resource for the real world. second lesson, ask your question correctly. show what this data structure is and what you think about it doesn't fit in the real world.

Comment: if you don't use data structures you will have many many array's which could be packed into one structure which would have one array linked to it. I'm guessing data structure means structure?

Comment: Before job you don't need to put the pseudocode into real code - because everything you learned is already implemented for ever language somewhere. On the job you will have to use your brain to _adapt_ what you learned onto the problem at hands. This is what you have to be good at, and why you have to know the concepts inside out. After you transformed your problem, you can feed it into the already-existing library call and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You should continue to search for a job *and* practice implementing and using data structures. Knowledge of the concepts is valuable, but it is far more valuable when combined with practical skill.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, the knowledge required to perform your job function is based a lot on the job profile you get. If you are looking for a job, then the companies you apply for might ask you concepts for data structures and may even ask you to code. But again, this depends on the company you have applied for. Nowadays, most established companies have their own set of APIs developed, and at the start of one's career, a developer is simple asked to use these APIs to develop small functionalities. So, most companies focus on a person knowing the concepts, and when you are working, you slowly pick up the skills to do API development.

Thus, if you are comfortable with programming, you should be good. Best of luck! :)